# Bash - Passing value to both console and variable/file

Tags: bash, logging, file-descriptor

I prepared a simple logger with a function `logMETHOD`:

```
function logMETHOD {
    exec 5>&1
    local log

    log="$( "$@" 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/5; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}>/tmp/ssg_retval )"
    local retVal=$(</tmp/ssg_retval)
    rm -f /tmp/ssg_retval

    _LOG_SSG+=$log$'\n'
    return $retVal
}
```

It is great. It puts output of a passed method into both console (through `/dev/fd/5`) AND variable `log` (through `/dev/fd/1`) at the same time. It also returns value returned by the passed method. Eg.

```
logMETHOD scp test.txt ala@host:/direcotry
```

It works, but unfortunately I can't use it, cause I have no access to `/dev/fd/5` on the server I need to use. "Permission denied".

I tried to use a temporary file instead of a file descriptor but it breaks dynamic output like `scp` progress bar.

Is there any way to implement this functionality without using file descriptors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have permission to use `&5` but not to use `/dev/fd/5`.  You could try to trace down why by running `ls -l /dev/fd/5` and comparing that to the user+group that your script runs under.  It may be simpler, though, to just try replacing:

```
tee /dev/fd/5;
```

With:

```
tee >(cat >&5)
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!